# How to customize lists in Latex without using frenchb package?

Tags: lists

I found that we can customize LaTeX lists like this (for example):

```
\begin{itemize}[font=\color{red},label=\ding{43}]
\item item1
\item item2
\end{itemize}
```

but to have such beautiful lists, we must load the packages

```
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
```

and add this instruction:

```
\frenchbsetup{StandardLists=true}
```

My problem is that I do not want to use the [`frenchb`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/french) package, I am writing an article in English language. How can I fix this trouble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break it down:

- `enumitem` is used for general customization of lists;
- `pifont` is used to get the `\ding` command;
- The only thing missing is the color. So simply load `xcolor` (I suppose that frenchb somehow loads it itself).

tl;dr: This does the trick:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[font=\color{red},label=\ding{43}]
\item item1
\item item2
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```